# session-descriptor not working for sharing sessions with weblogic

Tags: java, session, servlet-filters, weblogic12c

I have `localhost:8080/app1` (app1 is ear having 2 war projects and hence I added session descriptors to both weblogic.xml of war and weblogic-application.xml for ear) and want to access its session in `localhost:8080/app2`. app1 has authentication part so I want to access session of app1 in app2. Note app1 and app2 both are different ear.

weblogic.xml of one of the war file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" 
    xmlns:bae="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
<bae:session-descriptor>    
    <bae:persistent-store-type>memory</bae:persistent-store-type>
    <bae:sharing-enabled>true</bae:sharing-enabled>
</bae:session-descriptor> 

<wls:library-ref>
    <wls:library-name>jstl</wls:library-name>
    <wls:specification-version>1.2</wls:specification-version>
    <wls:exact-match>true</wls:exact-match>
</wls:library-ref>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

And weblogic-application.xml at ear level is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application 
  xmlns:bae="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
  xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.5/weblogic-application.xsd">
<!--weblogic-version:12.1.3-->
<wls:application-param>
    <wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
    <wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
</wls:application-param>

<bae:session-descriptor>    
    <bae:persistent-store-type>memory</bae:persistent-store-type>
    <bae:sharing-enabled>true</bae:sharing-enabled>
</bae:session-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

in app2, I have a filter where I have added code

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession(false);
```

And in this `session` object I also want to pass some custom attributes from app1 to app2.
I am new to weblogic configurations and not much aware of these in depth, tried these by reading [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/sessions.htm#WBAPP330) and [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/sessions.html) and obviously StackOverflow .

Any guidence or help or suggestions will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the applications are deployed in the same server, you could share the same session cookie name. You should use the same cookie name in both `weblogic.xml` war file deployment descriptors:

`weblogic.xml`

```xml
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>MY_COOKIE</cookie-name>
        <cookie-domain></cookie-domain>
        <cookie-path></cookie-path>
        <cookie-secure>false</cookie-secure>
        <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
```

This means you can reuse authentication from app1 in app2 web applications if the client is using a browser.

I think sending information from app1 to app2 through the Session object is not possible, you can try with EJB or JMS, both supported by Weblogic.

Comment: Cookie sharing is one of the options but this doesn't help me as I need to access session data as well. Secondly within same application, same host, weblogic document says it is possible to share sessions as mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webapp/sessions.html)

Comment: @kAmol it seems possible, just remember to use Serializable objects, but note the Session Sharing is for "web applications" and maybe it means only `.war` files. In fact, re-reading the documentation I think it only refers to "web applications" inside the same `.ear` deployment...